# How to use CONTAINS with CURDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table which contains the following values:

```
id | competition_id | season_id | name        | update_at
 1         5              512      2018/2019     2019-03-22 08:55:22
 2         5              NULL     Venezuela     NULL
 3         5              85       2017/2018     2019-02-15 08:55:22
 4         5              NULL     90'           NULL
 5         5              72       2016/2017     NULL
```

I need to return all the records which have the current year inside the `name` column, so I did:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name CONTAINS YEAR(CURDATE())
```

but I get:

> Syntax error in the SQL query near 'CONTAINS YEAR (CURDATE ()) LIMIT 0, 25' line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', YEAR(CURDATE()), '%');
```

Another solution using [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) or [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate):

```
-- using INSTR
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE INSTR(name, YEAR(CURDATE())) > 0;

-- using LOCATE
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE LOCATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), name) > 0;
```

You can also use the following solution using [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name REGEXP YEAR(CURDATE());
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a28af8a2617d068d20700beba4c26d2)

> **Note:** There is no function `CONTAINS` on MySQL to search a string in another string. `CONTAINS` [is a keyword on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C) and [can be used for spatial data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-mbr.html#function_contains) (earlier MySQL 8.0 - deprecated since MySQL 5.7.6).

Comment: there are more faster than `CONTAINS`?